# Как получить иерархию дочерних sql_Id всех вызываемых процедур в блоке?

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация, plsql, производительность

У меня есть блок кода, внутри которого вызываются другие процедуры. Схематично это выглядит так:

```
begin
  procedure_0;
  procedure_1;
  procedure_2;
  ....
end;
```

Внутри вызванных процедур выполняется различный DDL и DML. И вся это конструкция работает непозволительно долго. У меня есть `sql_id` этого блока из EM. Я хотел бы как то построить иерархию всех дочерних `sql_id` для этого блока и посмотреть, где сколько тратиться времени.

Подскажите, как можно решить такую задачу ?

Comment: Кто мешает в начало каждой процедуры добавить логирование факта её вызова в служебную таблицу? Если это приведёт к тормозам от большого количества инсертов - ну копить всё это в какой-то юзерской переменной, а на финише записывать.

Comment: Может [этот инструмент](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/hierarchical-profiler.html#GUID-B2E3A739-08C6-4648-A65F-1D093A0DADDE) заинтересует?

Comment: @Akina я хочу не только факт вызова копировать. Но и получить все `sql_id` для них. Потом посмотреть планы запросов и понять, где я могу что-то улучшить. В любом случае, добавить логгирование вызовов будет полезно(и я его сделаю), но проблему это не решит

Comment: *я хочу не только факт вызова копировать. Но и получить все sql_id для них* Ну получай, что мешает-то? можешь вообще весь стек вызовов записывать на каждом входе в каждую процедуру - на момент её вызова предыдущее состояние стека-то известно...

Comment: @Akina мне не понятно. Не могли бы вы это оформить ответом с примерами ??

Comment: А почему снятие обыкновенных трейсов не рассматриваете? Там вам будут все запросы с таймингом и прочей статистикой.

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin в лучших традициях ентерпрайз разработки обязанности разработки и администрирования разделены. Включить трейсы и полоучить их потом - это заявка к администратором, ожидание, боль. А потом еще эти трейсы и разобрать надо. Хотелось бы обойтись своими силами )

Comment: Можно в начале блока поместить установку `Module` или `Action` для сессии при помощи `dbms_application_info` и искать в `v$sql` по этим параметрам. Ещё один вариант: `v$sql` содержит `program_id` и `program_line#`, с помощью которых можно присоединиться к `user_objects` и `user_source` (если исходники открыты).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача легко решается с PL/SQL профайлером, который доступен с версии 11.1.

Функционал установлен по умолчанию. Надо только дать `EXECUTE` привилегию на пакет `DBMS_HPROF` и создать в схеме пару таблиц:

```sql
--AS SYS
SQL> grant execute on sys.dbms_hprof to you;
-- в целевой схеме
exec dbms_hprof.create_tables;
```

Пакет для попробовать:

```sql
create or  replace package pack0 as
    procedure starter;  
end;
/
create or replace package body pack0 as
    procedure starter is  
        res number;
        procedure proc1 is begin select 111 into res from dual; end;
        procedure proc2 is begin select 222 into res from dual; end;
        procedure proc3 is begin select 333 into res from dual; end;
    begin
        proc1;
        proc2;
        proc3;
    end starter;
end pack0;    
/
```

Вот так запустить и проанализировать данные профайлера:

```sql
set autoprint on
var runid  number;
exec -
    dbms_hprof.start_profiling ('TEMPFILES', 'pack0.trc'); -
    pack0.starter; -
    dbms_hprof.stop_profiling; -
    :runid := dbms_hprof.analyze ('TEMPFILES', 'pack0.trc', run_comment =>'prof pack0');

RUNID
-
1
```

Запрос и результат: искомые `sql_id` и время выполнения в микросекундах:

```sql
select 
    rpad (' ', (level-1)*2, ' ')||ltrim (fi.module||'.'||function, '.') name, 
    namespace ctx, sql_id, substr (sql_text, 1, 16) sqltxt, 
    fi.function_elapsed_time elapsed, fi.subtree_elapsed_time total 
from dbmshp_function_info fi
left join dbmshp_parent_child_info pci on (
    pci.runid = fi.runid and pci.childsymid = fi.symbolid)
where  fi.runid = :runid
connect by prior symbolid = parentsymid
and coalesce (owner, user) = user
start with parentsymid is null
/
NAME                               CTX   SQL_ID        SQLTXT              ELAPSED      TOTAL
---------------------------------- ----- ------------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
PACK0.STARTER                      PLSQL                                         5        323
  PACK0.STARTER.PROC1              PLSQL                                        44        136
    PACK0.__static_sql_exec_line4  SQL   gatp22snjsz4k SELECT 111 FROM          92         92
  PACK0.STARTER.PROC2              PLSQL                                        25         96
    PACK0.__static_sql_exec_line5  SQL   7z2m0xcm9hxmf SELECT 222 FROM          71         71
  PACK0.STARTER.PROC3              PLSQL                                        23         86
    PACK0.__static_sql_exec_line6  SQL   12rx46da4214c SELECT 333 FROM          63         63
DBMS_HPROF.STOP_PROFILING          PLSQL                                         0          0
```

Подробнее см. [Using the PL/SQL Hierarchical Profiler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/hierarchical-profiler.html#GUID-B2E3A739-08C6-4648-A65F-1D093A0DADDE)

Comment: Это восхитительно!